# Querying data from to nonrelated tables in SQL

Tags: sql, relational-database

I have a question in terms of SQL. Let's make up a simplified example with two tables:

Table A contains a period's **name**, its **start date** an its **end date**

Table B contains **dates**

What I want to do is to make a query, where I use Table B's date and in another column I want the Period to be shown.
Logically, I would use a condition like

Table B.date <= Table A.enddate
AND Table B.date >= Table A.startdate

to get the period's name, the date in question belongs to. However, as I cannot retate these two tables as table in a relational database are normally, I am currently stuck with this issue.

Comment: You are talking about a "theta join".

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample and the expected  result as tabular text

Comment: This is not clear. What does "I cannot relate these two tables as table in a relational database are normally" mean? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. For code questions give a [mre]. [ask] PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In relational database you typically see "equi-joins" where you relate tables using equality predicates.

However, you are not limited to these simple predicates. You can use **any predicate** you want to relate the tables. These are usually called "theta joins".

In your case you can do:

```
select a.*, b.*
from table_a a
join table_b b on b.date >= a.startdate and b.date <= a.enddate
```

Sample data:

```
create table table_a (name varchar(10), startdate date, enddate date);

insert into table_a (name, startdate, enddate) values
  ('Q1', '2021-01-01', '2021-03-31'),
  ('Q2', '2021-04-01', '2021-06-30'),
  ('Q3', '2021-07-01', '2021-09-30'),
  ('Q4', '2021-10-01', '2021-12-31');
  
create table table_b (date date);

insert into table_b (date) values ('2021-05-21'), ('2021-09-07');
```

Result:

```
 name  startdate   enddate     date      
 ----- ----------  ----------  ----------
 Q2    2021-04-01  2021-06-30  2021-05-21
 Q3    2021-07-01  2021-09-30  2021-09-07
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dsw7QFGNx26y55YQw87cF8/0).